# Google App Engine -- java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, struts2

I'm converting a Struts2 application to Google Apps.  I'm simply trying to call up the front page of my application and I get the following error on my console.  I do have commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar in my classpath.  Can anyone help me?  Is there another jar I need in addition to this?  Or is the problem something else?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.createGuid(Cache.java:1929)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:433)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:313)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createDefaultCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:246)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:286)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:218)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:205)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider.start(EhCacheProvider.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1005)
    at com.configuration.ConfigurationListener.contextInitialized(ConfigurationListener.java:19)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt my application without the GWT jar files.  That seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See this post:  [rmi error in google app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746043/rmi-error-in-google-app)

Its a little old, but sounds like it may still be valid.