# Error 500 while trying to upload file using apache commons . Logs say java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, noclassdeffounderror, apache-commons-fileupload

While trying to upload a file  into to my project folder *images* using apache commons following exception was generated :

I am copying these logs from the log viewer of google appengine.

```
2012-08-04 17:52:38.238 /UploadImagesToAisle 500 4381ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; 
Linux i686; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0

106.200.242.109 - - [04/Aug/2012:05:22:38 -0700] "POST /UploadImagesToAisle 
HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://programworks.appspot.com/ValidateCredentials" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0" 
"programworks.appspot.com" ms=4382 cpu_ms=1773 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.066922 
loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117ce6b4d0249c878697d13e1a0a649c

W 2012-08-04 17:52:38.178

Error for /UploadImagesToAisle
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.rmi.server.UID.<clinit>(UID.java)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.<clinit>(DiskFileItem.java:109)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:361)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
at Servlets.UploadImagesToAisle.doPost(UploadImagesToAisle.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)

........
```

I am trying to upload a file while using google appengine as the server and I am copying the file uploaded into my project directory. i.e inside a directory under *web-pages*.

Here is the servlet that I used to upload file :

```
   @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = request.getParameter("Data");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
     try {
       boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
       if( !isMultipart ) {
           writer.println("File cannot be uploaded !");
       } else {
           DiskFileItemFactory diskFileItem = new DiskFileItemFactory();
           ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(diskFileItem);
           List list = null;

           try {
               list = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
           }catch(Exception exc) {
               writer.println(exc);
           }

           Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
           while(iterator.hasNext()) {
              FileItem fileItem = (FileItem)iterator.next();
              if(fileItem.isFormField()) {
                  // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
              } else {
                  // Process form file field (input type="file").
                  String fieldName = fileItem.getFieldName();
                  String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileItem.getName());
                  File file = new File("images/",fileName);
                  fileItem.write(file);
              }
           }
       }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        writer.println(exc);
    }
}
```

*Html snippet*

```
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../../UploadImagesToAisle">
            <input type="file" name="Data"/>
            <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
        </form>
```

*Images* directory inside the project where I want to upload the file :

[image]

Comment: Look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746043/rmi-error-in-google-app

Comment: and  https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#fileforms

Comment: or use  http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html

Comment: or there is experimnetal, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

Comment: @rickz in that how do I write the file into my war directory?  Using apache streaming

Comment: Google App Engine doesn't allow file writing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write to the file system in Google App Engine. All the applications are sand-boxed. They can only read the files that are uploaded with the project and cannot write to the filesystem. This is the reason you are getting this error.

To overcome this you can make use of [Google App Engine Virtual File System](http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/). Its a library that is implemented using GAE datastore and memcache APIs. 
This might help.

EDIT:
Add the library file downloaded at http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/downloads/detail?name=gaevfs-0.3.zip&can=2&q= to your web server.
Try this and shoot comments:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = request.getParameter("Data");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
     try {
       boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
       if( !isMultipart ) {
           writer.println("File cannot be uploaded !");
       } else {

           ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload();
           List list = null;

           try {
               list = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
           }catch(Exception exc) {
               writer.println(exc);
           }

           Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
           while(iterator.hasNext()) {
              FileItem fileItem = (FileItem)iterator.next();
              if(fileItem.isFormField()) {
                  // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
              } else {
                  // Process form file field (input type="file").
                  String fieldName = fileItem.getFieldName();
                  String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileItem.getName());
                  GaeVFS.setRootPath( getServletContext.getRealPath( "/" ) );
                  FileSystemManager fsManager = GaeVFS.getManager();
                    FileObject file = fsManager.resolveFile( "gae://images/"+filename );
                  fileItem.write(file);
              }
           }
       }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        writer.println(exc);
    }
}
```

Add this at import:

```
import org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemManager;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject;
import com.newatlanta.commons.vfs.provider.gae.GaeVFS;
```

Comment: But there will be a way out to use apache commons.and I have to write the file into my project directory

Comment: GAEVFS is also a apache commons project. Its is also similar in functionality. instead of ordinary filesystem use GAEVFS in your project. thats it. Review the API here http://commons.apache.org/vfs/api.html

Comment: For uploading you have to combine both fileupload and GAEVFS.. get the inputstream from fileupload and then to write it to FileOutputStream obtained from doGetOutputStream() method of GaeFileObject.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Does this method of uploading help your need?

Comment: No.Till now I have been unable to identify,how to upload file using GAEVFS. Are there any tutorials around for this ? May be you can help

Comment: add your current uploading code part, i'll do modify it for GAEVFS,,

Comment: It is there in the question. And it will be very helpful if you modify it for GAEVFS

Comment: did you modify it for GAEVFS ?

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I will just check if that works. Can you tell me what does `gae://images/` this mean ? Is `gae://` some kind of protocol ? Can I use code this to write files in any of my project directory ?

Comment: yes, gae:/ is the protocol for GAEVFS Files.. you can use it similarly for other files.

Comment: the last statement _fileItem.write(file);_ gives an error. It says required java.io.File but found org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject. Even if I cast it,I get the same exception `Error for /UploadImagesToAisle java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class.` Why am I getting that now ?

Comment: what is this : `OutputStream out=file.doGetOutputStream(false)` ? There isn't any method named _doGetOutputStream_

Comment: -1 : the program doesn't work and is the way you handle upload to GAE ? !

Comment: can you please revert back to your old answer !

Comment: @grassPro If so your help would me much appreciated.

Comment: After it is checked whether the file is _mutipart_ or not I have modified the else block  [like this](http://i47.tinypic.com/4f9u9.png) . I have used streaming API http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html . Now can I have the last GAE code please. I think it will surely upload the file if we combine your last GAE code with this one

Comment: @SuhailGupta Revived back the answer. Use it and check.

Comment: aah ! but there is one problem , we don't have `fileItem` object anymore. How do I write the file now ? !

Comment: I could have done but there is similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903367/uploading-a-file-using-apache-streaming-api-and-google-app-engine-virtual-file-s#11903367

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it was incorrect. Run that code and you will come to know. And how you say I have duplicated the question ? Read both of them carefully and you will come to know. You haven't been able to solve the OP problem till now and mind that. The question there doesn't ask the reason for any 500 error.