# uploading a file using apache streaming API and Google App Engine Virtual File System

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, apache-commons

To upload a file into my project directory which is there on the google appengine,I am trying to use [apache streaming API](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html) and [Google App Engine Virtual File System](http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/). Here is what I have been able to do till now :

```
    String path = request.getParameter("Data");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
     try {
       boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
       if( !isMultipart ) {
           writer.println("File cannot be uploaded !");
       }
       else {
           ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
           FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
           List list = null;
           while(iter.hasNext()) {
               FileItemStream item = iter.next();
               String name  = item.getFieldName();
               String fileName = item.getName();
               InputStream stream = item.openStream();
               if(item.isFormField()) {
                   // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
               } else {
                   GaeVFS.setRootPath( getServletContext().getRealPath("/") );
                   FileSystemManager fsManager = GaeVFS.getManager();
                   //....NOW WHAT....

               }
           }
       }
```

I am stuck there in the else block. How to proceed now ? I have to write the file to a directory named *uploads* in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE filesystem is read-only. There is [no write access](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#writefile) via an API. The only way to change filesystem contents is to update the app via `appcfg`.

If you need to upload data and store it use [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overviewhttp://).

**Upload to blobstore:**

```
String path = request.getParameter("Data");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
 try {
   boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
   if( !isMultipart ) {
       writer.println("File cannot be uploaded !");
   }
   else {
       ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
       FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
       List list = null;
       while(iter.hasNext()) {
           FileItemStream item = iter.next();
           String name  = item.getFieldName();
           String fileName = item.getName();
           InputStream stream = item.openStream();
           if(item.isFormField()) {
               // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
           } else {

            // Get a file service
            FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

            // Create a new Blob file with mime-type "text/plain"
            AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(mimeType, filename);

            // Open a channel to write to it
            boolean lock = true;
            FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);

            // copy byte stream from request to channel
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            int len;
            while ((len = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, len));
            }

            writeChannel.closeFinally();

            // here your data is saved to blobstore
            // you should now save a blobstore key somewhere (=to a datastore)
            // so that you can find it next time
            String blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file).getKeyString();

           }
       }
   }
```

**Serving a blob:**

```
public class BlobServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String blobParameter = request.getParameter("blob-key");
    if (blobParameter == null) {
        response.sendError(404, "Missing 'blob-key' parameter.");
    }

    BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(blobParameter);

    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (15 * 60));   // 15 min
    BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().serve(blobKey, response);
}
}
```

**Registering your servlet:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BlobServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yourpackage.BlobServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BlobServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/blobservet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Referencing blob in your JSP:**

```
<a src="/blobserve?<%=blobKey%>">Link to blob</a>
```

Comment: but then what is GAEVFS meant for ?

Comment: there has to be a way of uploading data using apache commons and GAEVFS

Comment: As far as I see GAEVFS uses memcache (volatile) and datastore (max 1MB blob)

Comment: Btw here is an example upload servlet: http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/source/browse/trunk/src/com/newatlanta/appengine/servlet/GaeVfsServlet.java

Comment: thanks for the example. The code there uploads a file using apache commons streaming API.Is there any upload limit to that ? I don't think so.I want to upload the file to a directory named _uploads_ that is within my project.How do I specify the directory ?

Comment: As explained in the answer - you can not do that. This filesystem is read-only. So GAEVFS allows you to read those files, but not write to them.

Comment: I don't understand you.The servlet you cited tells how to upload files to GAE and then you say the file system is read only. please help me understand this

Comment: The servlet uploads data into datastore, not filesystem.

Comment: portion where my project's _war_ lies is the filesystem which is read only..I see.It means I cannot upload a file to that portion where my project's _war_ lies. Am i correct ? And is _Blobstore_ the same as _Datastore_ ?

Comment: Correct - you war is unpacked into a local filesystem, which is read-only. No, blobstore is not the same as datastore. Blobstore is simple storage for unstructured binary blobs, while Datastore is a full-fledged NoSQL database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15208/discussion-between-grasspro-and-peter-knego)

Comment: Can you in very simple words explain the difference between datastore and blobstore ?
Let us suppose there is a file there in anyone of the store (either blobstore or datastore) is there any way I can make a reference to them from a jsp page ? Like `<img src="pathtoStore/ImageFromStore.png" />`

Comment: No, you can not make direct reference. You have to have a servlet that serves the file from either of stores and then you can reference it in  your JSP. But serving file from blobstore is really trivial: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob

Comment: If you call serving file from blobstore trivial,then what is nontrivial ? I cannot upload file to the GAE filesystem,serving blob from blobstore is trivial. What should I do then ?

Comment: No, you upload file to blobstore and serve it from blobstore. Your upload code is already halfway there. I'll give you a hand - answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the helping hand in code.But I have two doubts regarding the file upload code you have posted. What is `is` in the while loop that writes a file to the channel ? `len = is.read(buffer)) > 0` You have asked to save the blobkey for future reference.Where is it ?

Comment: Edited. You have to be led by hand do you?

Comment: can you explain the reason for this : `response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (15 * 60))` in the code to serve the blob

Comment: Google uses transparent cache that honors `Cache-control` headers: http://davepeck.org/2011/10/25/a-word-on-app-engine-caching/